# How to get url parameter in Model/ResourceModel/agent/Grid/Collection.php

Tags: magento2

```
 protected function _initSelect()
{
    parent::_initSelect();
    $agent_id = $this->request->getParam('agent_id');

}
```

Try to get "agent_id" from url but getting this eror

```
Type Error occurred when creating object: Magedelight\DeliveryAgent\Model\ResourceModel\DeliveryAgentShipment\Grid\Collection\Interceptor, Argument 1 passed to Magedelight\DeliveryAgent\Model\ResourceModel\DeliveryAgentShipment\Grid\Collection\Interceptor::__construct() must implement interface Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface, instance of Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactory given, called in /var/www/html/CE/241/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 121
```

construct signature

```
public function __construct(
  \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
    EntityFactory $entityFactory,
    Logger $logger,
    FetchStrategy $fetchStrategy,
    EventManager $eventManager,
    $mainTable = 'magedelight_delivery_agent_shipment',
    $resourceModel = "Magedelight\DeliveryAgent\Model\ResourceModel\DeliveryAgentShipment",
    $identifierName = null,
    $connectionName = null
) {
    $this->request = $request;
    parent::__construct(
        $entityFactory,
        $logger,
        $fetchStrategy,
        $eventManager,
        $mainTable,
        $resourceModel,
        $identifierName,
        $connectionName
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can getby injecting **Http** class to **__construct**

```
protected $request;

public function __construct(
    ...
     \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
    ...
) {
    $this->request = $request;
}

public function getRequestData()
{
    return $this->request->getParam('agent_id');
}
```

Comment: I tried this but getting same error. this one

Type Error occurred when creating object: Model\ResourceModel\DeliveryAgentShipment\Grid\Collection\Interceptor, Argument 1 passed to Model\ResourceModel\DeliveryAgentShipment\Grid\Collection\Interceptor::__construct() must implement interface Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface, instance of Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactory given, called in /var/www/html/CE/241/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 121

Comment: can you please show me your constructor signature?

Comment: Edit above please check